# How to shorten a Haskell implementation like this?

Tags: haskell

I have a function with a lot of guards that look like this:

```
function 
    | p `elem` [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
    | p `elem` [7,8,9,10,11,12,13] = [7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
    | p `elem` [14,15,16,17,18,19,20] = [14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
    | otherwise = []
```

I'm sure I can write this much shorter with Haskell. If not, then it's okay. I'm new to Haskell and I would love to become better at it by learning different approaches.

Perhaps using "map" may be a good start? But then, I'm not sure how to pass in those specific lists.

The values are not always contiguous.

Comment: are the blocks of numbers always contiguous values in groups of 7?

Comment: @jamshidh They are always in groups of 7 but not always containing consecutive values.

Comment: For this specific function, I would be tempted to write something like `function p = [lo .. lo+6] where lo = 7 * div p 7`.

Comment: @DanielWagner: this function does not return the empty list in case `p` is less than zero or greater than 20.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, I know. I consider that a feature. =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about simple bounds checks?

```
function p
    | p < 0 = [] 
    | p < 7 = [0..6]
    | p < 14 = [7..13]
    | p < 21 = [14..20]
    | otherwise = []
```

It will be faster and for some applications use less memory.

If you don't want to perform a bounds check (but an element check), you can still use the shortened list notation.

---

Alternatively, you could construct a helper function that iterates over the lists:

```
helper (x:xs) p | elem p x = x
                | otherwise = helper xs p 
helper [] _ = []

function = helper [[0..6],[7..13],[14..20]]
```

Although this is actually longer, you can easily extend the `function` to use other lists. Note however that this function will be slower, since `elem` requires *O(n)* time whereas a bounds check takes *O(1)* time.

---

You can also - as is suggested in [@jamshidh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36878452/67579) construct a `Data.Map` which is a datastructure that guarantees *O(log n)* lookup time:

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Maybe(fromMaybe)

helper2 :: Ord a => [[a]] -> a -> [a]
helper2 lst p = fromMaybe [] $ Map.lookup p (Map.fromList $ concatMap (\x -> zip x (repeat x)) lst)

function = helper2 [[0..6],[7..13],[14..20]]
```

For this last piece, it generates `(\x -> zip x (repeat x))` generates for a list tuples containing an element of the list `e` and the entire list `l`. For example:

```
Prelude> (\x -> zip x (repeat x)) [0..6]
[(0,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]),(1,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]),(2,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]),(3,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]),(4,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]),(5,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]),(6,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6])]
```

This works as follows: `x` unifies with a list, for instance `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]`, now we apply a `zip` function on `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]` and on the infinite list `[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],....]`. [`zip`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip) generates tuples as long as both lists feed elements, so it takes the first element from `[0,1,..,6]` and the first from `[[0,1,..,6],[0,1,..,6],[0,1,..,6],...]` so the resulting tuple is `(0,[0..6])`, next it takes the second element `1` from the list, and the second item from the `repeat` function, thus `(1,[0..6])`. It keeps doing this -- although lazily -- until one of the lists is exhausted which is the case for the first list.

Comment: According to the question, the values are not always contiguous. So this unfortunately won't work.

Comment: Oh wow, why didn't I think of that! Thanks! This works for some of the conditions. :)

Comment: @Sibi: therefore I've updated the question with two additional alternatives.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Let me make sure I'm understanding how the last approach works.

I'm confused about how this portion (\x -> zip x (repeat x)) works. Is it just generating an infinite list of x values to pair with the input list?

Comment: @heysharynne: no it generates tuples of `(i,l)` with `i` an item in the list and `l` the entire list. I will update the answer.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh I see. It is simply making a tuple of an element in the list and the list that contains it which makes lookup possible. Similar-ish to how hashing work, right?

Comment: Yes, but as far as I know a `Map` is implemented as binary search tree. It simply accepts as input a list of key/value tuples and will store them in the binary search tree.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the list monad here.

```
func p = join $ do x <- [[1,3,5], [2,4,6], [7,8,9]]
                   guard $ p `elem` x
                   return x
```

The list of lists are the things you want to check against. The call to `guard` filters out the choices that don't succeed. As long as the candidate lists are disjoint, at most one will succeed. `return x` evaluates to either `[]` or `[x]` for one of the choices of `x`, so `join`
reduces `[x]` to `[]`.

```
> func 1
[1,3,5]
> func 2
[2,4,6]
> func 7
[7,8,9]
> func 10
[]
```

As a list comprehension, it would look like

```
func p = join [x | x <-[[1,3,5],[2,4,6],[7,8,9]], p `elem` x]
```

Comment: I'm almost certain that there is a way to take the *first*, rather than the *only*, choice of `x` for which `elem p x` is true.

Answer (score 4):

First create the list of lists

```
lists = [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6], [7,8,9,10,11,12,13], [14,15,16,17,18,19,20]]
```

Then create a mapping from value to list

```
theMap = concat $ map (\x -> zip x (repeat x)) lists
```

This will give you what you need

```
> lookup 1
Just [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Note that the output is a `Maybe`, in the case you don't supply a value in any list.

Comment: How does this affect the efficiency of the program? Is it any faster?

Comment: This definitely beats using `elem`, I believe

Comment: If you convert to Map (using fromList), then once the mapping is created, it will be much faster, because you won't have to traverse the list using `elem`.  I kept it at standard list lookup, but map works the same way.

Comment: @jamshidh: only problem I can still think of is that it will not return `[]` in case not found. You can solve this however using `fromMaybe`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think the Maybe is actually a better output than empty list (even though the question shows otherwise).  You are correct though, converting is easy.

Comment: 2nd that. Did +1 btw :)